# Magento : Fatal Error While Migrating From Magento 1.5.1 to 1.6.2

Tags: upgrade, magento-1.6

I have following error after my upgrade :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Model_Config::getResourceHelper() in /home/koala/dev/magento/koala/app/Mage.php on line 531
```

I ve set up some debug here :

```
/**
 * Retreive resource helper object
 *
 * @param string $moduleName
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Helper_Abstract
 */
public static function getResourceHelper($moduleName)
{
    $registryKey = '_resource_helper/' . $moduleName;
    var_dump($registryKey);
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getResourceHelper($moduleName);
        self::register($registryKey, $helperClass);
    }

    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

And the resource helper called is :

```
string(21) "_resource_helper/core"
```

Does anyone had and fixed this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Google helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28475293/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-magegetresourcehelper-in-mage-core-mod/30505243

Comment: Check `getResourceHelper` function in Mage.php

Comment: @PankajPareek sorry i edited my question, error is in fact in Mage.php call of app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php file but I don't know what s going badly there

Comment: I had a deeper look and all the calls to core getResourceHelper are made by magento from core folder, not a single thing is calling this in local so it is not due to custom developments

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this, we had in local an override on app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php that was broken

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/93551)

Comment: In this override function was missing, so basically once added, it works